# Bad encoding when using on strftime in spanish?

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo the date with strftime but I'm getting bad encoding on utf-8 only characters. (accented characters basically)

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
define("CHARSET", "iso-8859-1");
echo strftime("%A, %d de %B",strtotime($row['Date']));
```

Is there any problem in this part of the code? Everything is encoded in utf-8 and echoing a 'á' character above it displays the character correctly.

Comment: what error you are getting, i run your code in codepad and found nothing inappropriate, let me know whr u face problem http://codepad.org/YWGGJ1tW

Comment: How do you see the result? In browser? Are you sure the problem is in the code and not in the way you are seeing the output? Also, do not use strtotime - its very bad practice, as its a black box, if the date you supply it is 06/07/11 - what would be the result (which one is year, month, date)?

Comment: I'm getting a black diamond with an interrogative sign inside. I cannot tell for sure, but I don't think the problem is in the way I'm seeing it since echoing `echo "á".strftime("%A",strtotime($row['Date']));` shows the á correctly but doesn´t print sábado correctly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try adding utf8_encode()

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
define("CHARSET", "iso-8859-1");
echo utf8_encode(strftime("%A, %d de %B",strtotime($row['Date'])));
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm a bit late, but Googling around I found this post. And the answers weren't appropriate in my case.
I'm experiencing the same problem as the OP, but my locale is fr_FR and everything works fine on my computer but not on the dev server.

If I add an iconv (as most people suggest when you Google this issue), it works on the dev server but not on my computer, so I needed a "bulletproof" solution that would work the same everywhere (as there is also a production server).

So, the issue here is with the `setlocale`, this function changes the locale on the current execution, but every locale is associated with a charset and if none is specified, it falls back to the default one of your system (I think, in my case it was falling back to ISO-8859-1 when using the fr_FR locale). You can list all available locales on your computer/server with the `locale -a` command. You will most likely see the locale you want, with ".UTF-8" (in my case "fr_FR.UTF-8"), that's how you must set it: `setlocale('fr_FR.UTF-8');`

Comment: You were right, this is the way to fix it. I've tested in Spanish.

Answer (score 4):

perhaps:

```
echo iconv("iso-8859-1","utf-8",strftime("%A, %d %B",strtotime($row['Date'])));
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that don't have iconv, you can use the mb function to convert the stftime encoded string to utf-8

```
echo mb_convert_encoding(strftime("%A, %d de %B",strtotime($row['Date'])), 'UTF-8', mb_internal_encoding());
```